# Unity Smartphone Application connecting with a heart rate monitor

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy, smartphone

I am trying to make a smartphone application in Unity.
This application/game should react on your heart rate. 
Now I wonder how I can do this things as there isn't a lot of information about this topic.

I'm hoping if someone has suggestions/experience in how to do this and which heart monitor devices could be used? I was thinking about a BLE heart monitor device, but I don't find any information about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some plugins available that you can use for heart rate (*remember i never use any of this and i am not guarantteed that it will work 100 percent correctly*) input in unity3d. 
like [Heart Rate Plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8497) or [HoloLens Heart Rate Monitor Plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/76113)